# What is the difference to choose SDR or DDR mode of OSPI flash to use in reality?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, flash-memory

My assumption is the SoC can support both protocol OSPI SDR and DDR. With an embedded system designer, if he can choose between SDR or DDR mode of OSPI flash device to deploy on his board, what is the point to consider? I mean the advanced feature such as speed, bandwidth, latency, persistence, etc...

In my opinion, DDR mode always outperform SDR mode so where we can use SDR mode?

Comment: This question is off topic in this site, try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. You would necessarily use SDR on a device lacking DDR support, beyond that the question is about comparing data sheets; you could do that yourself.

Comment: thank Clifford. I will reask on that site

Comment: note my comment is a prime example of why you should select the right site to get the right experts; I have only just noticed that you were not referring to SDRAM.  I would imagine the differences are performance and cost. The lowest cost part that is fast enough is how you would choose for volume production

Comment: I saw this was asked on the other site, should this one get closed?

Comment: its often a case of cost vs performance, so opinion based.  alternate part choices, cost per part, number of signals to route, requirements for the quality of the signal routing, etc...so the slower, fewer bit options have value.

Comment: Yes cost vs performance vs complexity will be the key to choose. Thank old-timer